# WordPress "The Loop" Issues with "endwhile"

Tags: php, wordpress

For some reason my editor is giving me a error `<?php endwhile; ?>` and I'm not sure why. It says its a `syntax error`. If anyone could maybe take the time to check out my code and see if its a bug in the editor or if I did anything wrong it would be more than appreciated!

> Edit::::: The page wont load either I posted a picture of the error I get below...

**Huge Thanks in Advance!!!**

```
    <div class="homepage-slider-container">
        <div class="homepage-slider">
            <?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'feature', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby'=> 'ASC')); ?>
            <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <a href="#" class="prev"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/slide-left-arrow.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="#" class="next"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/slide-right-arrow.png" alt=""></a>

            <div class="slide">
                <?php $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, "url", true);
                if($url!='') {
                    echo '<a href="'.$url.'">';
                    echo '
                ?>
                <div class="homepage-slider-title">
                    <span class="title-rectangle">
                        <article>
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            <div class="clear"><!-- Clear --></div>
                            <p><?php the_content();?></p>
                        </article>
                    </span>
                    <!-- This is the right arrow that is attached to the title rectangle -->
                    <div class="title-rectangle-right_arrow"> </div>
                    <!-- This is the arrow that is to the right of the title text area -->
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/slider-title-right-arrow.gif" class="title-rectangle-further_right_arrow" alt="">
                    <?php '; echo the_post_thumbnail('full');
                echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

            <div class="homepage-slider-front_pedestal">
                <p><?php echo of_get_option('slider_front-pedestal', 'no entry'); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: WordPress Errors]

Comment: your not closing your `if` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
<div class="homepage-slider-container">
    <div class="homepage-slider">
        <?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'feature', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby'=> 'ASC')); ?>
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <a href="#" class="prev"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/slide-left-arrow.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href="#" class="next"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/slide-right-arrow.png" alt=""></a>

        <div class="slide">
            <?php $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, "url", true);
            if($url!='') {
                echo '<a href="'.$url.'">';
            ?>
            <div class="homepage-slider-title">
                <span class="title-rectangle">
                    <article>
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <div class="clear"><!-- Clear --></div>
                        <p><?php the_content();?></p>
                    </article>
                </span>
                <!-- This is the right arrow that is attached to the title rectangle -->
                <div class="title-rectangle-right_arrow"> </div>
                <!-- This is the arrow that is to the right of the title text area -->
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/slider-title-right-arrow.gif" class="title-rectangle-further_right_arrow" alt="">
                <?php echo the_post_thumbnail('full');
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

        <div class="homepage-slider-front_pedestal">
            <p><?php echo of_get_option('slider_front-pedestal', 'no entry'); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You have an erroeneous echo, which doesn't echo anything. Took out some single quotes + an echo/semi-colon.

As you have closed the PHP tag, it is no longer echo-ing out, it is working with normal HTML. :) So no need for the echo before the closing PHP tag.

Comment: the blank echo was supposed to echo out all the content

Comment: but ur code doesnt close the if statement will that if statement include the html code?

Comment: There is no need for it when you have closed the PHP tags. When you closed the PHP tags you tell the server - Quit being PHP, and just output all this stuff now as normal code, until the next PHP tag.

Also, your code doesn't close the `if` either, you will need to add that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete version:

```
    <div class="homepage-slider-container">
    <div class="homepage-slider">
        <?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'feature', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby'=> 'ASC')); ?>
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <a href="#" class="prev"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/slide-left-arrow.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href="#" class="next"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/slide-right-arrow.png" alt=""></a>

        <div class="slide">
            <?php $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, "url", true);
            if($url!='') {
                echo '<a href="'.$url.'">';
            ?>
            <div class="homepage-slider-title">
                <span class="title-rectangle">
                    <article>
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <div class="clear"><!-- Clear --></div>
                        <p><?php the_content();?></p>
                    </article>
                </span>
                <!-- This is the right arrow that is attached to the title rectangle -->
                <div class="title-rectangle-right_arrow"> </div>
                <!-- This is the arrow that is to the right of the title text area -->
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/slider-title-right-arrow.gif" class="title-rectangle-further_right_arrow" alt="">
                <?php echo the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

        <div class="homepage-slider-front_pedestal">
            <p><?php echo of_get_option('slider_front-pedestal', 'no entry'); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no? what I echo is all the content.. note the <?php '; echo the_post_thumbnail('full'); at the end

Comment: No you don't :) Do what i say, also, remove from <?php '; echo the_post_thumbnail('full'); the <?php '; part :)

Comment: so if I have if($url!='') { then close off the php with ?> then have my HTML content then I could close it off with <?php } ?> and it would display the html content?

Comment: Exactly. You can start a php block, then end it add html, then start again

Comment: You should not echo `the_post_thumbnail()`.